# Deployment of Web Application with ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse

I have developped a web dynamic application using JSP and servlet and I want to deploy it.
How to do it with eclipse.
how to do to launch the application.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) to deploy your application. You can easily integrate Tomcat into the Eclipse.
http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html

Alternatively, instead of plugin, you can add the server into the Eclipse. 
Ctrl -N > Server > Select Tomcat Server adapter

If you've developed your application as 'Dynamic Web Project' in Eclipse, the above process will detect your application, and asks you to select if it has to be deployed in the new server configuration.

To generate war file, right click on your project in 'project explorer' window, and click 'export as'. In the dialog box, select WEB > WAR file

Comment: I mean to have the war and run the application finally.